Is there a website that has all the special functions?
There are a lot of special functions, and I wonder if there is a website that collects all of them, similar to how the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers collects information on triangle centers.
Another question is: What are the criteria for defining a new special function? One can define anything if they want to, so is there any established criteria for what would be considered and accepted as a new special function?
For example I  can just define a function like  $\Theta(x)$ to be the inverse function for $e^{\sin(x)}\cos(x)+ 5x^x-\Gamma(\gamma x) $  where $x\in [0, \frac \pi 2 ]$ Now this is a new function, what one should do to make similar functions an "acceptable" special function? I think  a function to be considered a new one is that it can't be obtained via definite combinations of the known functions.
In geometry if one discovers a new triangle center he can just submit it to ETC I wonder if  a similar thing exist for special functions?

It seems like the such websites don't exist but I think a websites  that collects special functions like how ETC collect triangle centers is a good idea that I want to make this website but I don't have enough knowledge in mathematics or programming  to make such thing I wonder whether I can request such Idea in MSE or MO for the community ton do.

You might start with Wikipedia: List of mathematical functions

I doubt that there is a website that collects all special functions, but the NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions does a pretty good job.

There are many special functions defined in literature, like these ones, but not many would consider them standard special functions, like those in the DLMF.

The Wolfram Language & System Special Functions page claims "by far the world's broadest and deepest coverage of special functions". How this compares to the NIST Digital Library, I couldn't say.

They are infinity many special functions. Thus no site can show all. I suppose that you mean "standard" special functions. In other words the special functions which are standardised at present time. Of course such a list of standard special functions would change each time a new one appears. But how a function becomes a standard function is not well defined. The preceeding comments gives some pertinent  lists. At lower level, a paper for general public : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales pp.18-36.
